# Absence of Request mapping in spring framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

[image]

It shows:

> Request Mapping can not be resolved to a type.

Comment: Code is preferred to images as it can be [searched for and tested out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/12892553) and in addition [Users from certain countries can't view hosted images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407369/12892553)

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse IDE sometimes this error comes while using Java 1.8. To resolve this error you have to perform 2 actions:-

1. Modify Build Path:- The tools.jar file in the lib folder of Java1.8 needs be to added as additional JARs. See steps [here](https://bigphu.tistory.com/87). Go to Project => Properties => Java Build Path => Libraries => JRE System Libraries => Edit. Click Alternative JRE => Installed JREs => click on jre1.8 => Edit. In Edit JRE windows, add extranal JAR "tools.jar" from the JDK installation path => Apply and close.
2. Modify Project Facets:- Go to Project => Properties => Project Facets => Adjust the Java version => Click on Apply.

Answer (score -1):

You should define HTTP method type, Get, post, put etc. As below

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```